# Laptop crashes when power cord is unplugged - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Recently my power cord failed, so I purchased a new one. This new one works fine (charges etc.) But when I unplug it, my laptop crashes. (The laptop just turns off completely. No blue screen.) Before this, my battery could last a good 2 hours before needing to be plugged in. At the event of the crash, my battery full (due to the fact I can't unplug it..). Does anyone have any idea what the problem is? Or what I can do to fix it?

I cannot boot my computer without the cable plugged in.

The power cord I purchased has the same specs as my old one.

Comment: Better to have your battery replaced with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue on multiple Lenovo Laptops with Intel and AMD graphics(switchable). Whenever I unplug the power cord, laptops were crashing with blue screen. Issue was not resolved even after updating the graphics driver.

To fix the issue, right click on Desktop -> Graphics properties -> Click on Power Icon -> Click on On Battery -> Disable " Display refresh rate switching" option.

Once this option is disabled there will be no screen flickering whenever you plug or unplug the power cord. However graphics card switching happens seamlessly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the **battery** is no longer really holding a charge, no matter what the computer claims, in this case you’d need to purchase a new battery.
Or maybe it is a **power management setting** which I think it's the case. There is a power switching utility that quickly switches between AC and Battery when the power cable/charger is plugged in or unplugged while the laptop is on. If you have it set it to “always on”. In HP laptops that switching utility is called “Rixane Power Scheme” if you don't have HP select the “Portable/Laptop” power scheme if on Windows XP. On Windows 7 go to “Power Options” -> “Change Plan Settings” -> “Change advanced power settings” -> “Battery” -> “Low battery Level” -> “on battery” change the value to 1% or 0%. Then expand the “Low battery action” and change the “on battery” option. Set "Battery->Critical battery action->On battery: Do nothing" 
Or **connector socket** where the power source plug is inserted might perhaps have been damaged or stressed physically.

Comment: What do you mean by power scheme? Are you talking about the power settings like Balanced, Power Saver, and High Performance?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question. Hope it helps! @user3788604

Comment: Well I have no option for "Portable/Laptop", only the ones I listed above.

Comment: I have edited. "Portable/Laptop" scheme is for Windows XP sorry. Select "High performance" in "Power Options" and then "Change plan settings" as explained in answer. @user3788604

Comment: In the "Critical battery action" section, the only options are for sleep, hibernate, or shut down. There is no "Do nothing" setting. What should I set this section to?

Comment: Try setting "critical battery level" also to the lowest possible and put action to sleep.

Comment: If that doesn't work then it's either battery or some mechanical problem like connector socket in my opinion. @user3788604

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. But if it was the power socket, how would I receive any power at all? My laptop is still able to turn on while connected to power.